# How to use sql to get a representative evenly distributed subset from a data set with latitude and longitude？

Tags: mysql, gis, postgis, spatial, uniform-distribution

I have some data with latitude and longitude information, but most of the data points are geographically dense and not representative. I hope to pick a representative subset with uniform distribution from these data sets.

Below is my data example

```
no lon     lat
1  121.62  31.18
2  121.91  30.90
3  121.76  31.11
4  121.49  31.12
... ...
```

I checked some information, learned to group latitude and longitude, and then use Pearson chi-square test, but I am not familiar with the use of sql.

I hope to get sql code to get such a subset or better use sql to get even distribution Methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually bucket the points by some grid, and select one (random) point from each cell. If the area is relatively small, you can use GeoHash as bucket Id. To select an arbitrary point, use `ANY_VALUE` aggregate (it is a strange aggregate function that returns arbitrary element from a group - not truly random, but probably good enough here).

The query would be something like

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(geo_point)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ST_MakePoint(lon, lat) as geo_point,
    ST_GeoHash(lon, lat, <level>) as geo_hash
  FROM <table>
)
GROUP BY geo_hash
```

For larger areas GeoHash is not a good choice as it is much more dense near poles than near equator, and the solution would depend on how complicated you want it to be :). Either ignore the problem, and keep using GeoHash, or maybe switch to S2 cell id which offers more uniform distribution, or create some custom grid and find grid id for each point using ST_Intersects condition.

Comment: I did not find this function ST_GeomPoint(lon, lat). How did he achieve it?

Comment: Yeah, did not check function name. Looks like MySql uses just 'Point' function to construct points, and PostGis uses ST_MakePoint.